# Python changes Integer in Float by itself

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I'm trying to learn Python, (i have 2.5.4) by writing a snake game, but I'm stuck.
Some integers change into floats and keep changing randomly, at least from my perspective :)

The problem is that `Snake.spawnPoint` gets changed by `Cam.move()`

```
print Snake.spawnPoint # first time, this returns '[25, 20]' ,which is good.
Cam.Move()
print Snake.spawnPoint # after the method, the value is '[26.0, 21.0]', and that's bad
```

After that, they just drift around.

And this is the method: (it has nothing to do with the `spawnPoint`

```
def Move(self):
    self.vel[0]+=(self.target[0]-self.cen[0])*self.k
    self.vel[1]+=(self.target[1]-self.cen[1])*self.k
    if    self.vel[0] > self.friction: self.vel[0]-= self.friction
    elif  self.vel[0] < self.friction: self.vel[0]+= self.friction
    else: self.vel[0] = 0
    if    self.vel[1] > self.friction: self.vel[1]-= self.friction
    elif  self.vel[1] < self.friction: self.vel[1]+= self.friction
    else: self.vel[1]=0
    self.cen[0]+=self.vel[0]
    self.cen[1]+=self.vel[1]
```

The `spawnPoint` is a constant that I append to the snake's body when he spawns. I like it to be a list because it have the snake's body made of lists, and the rendering method uses `index()` to do stuff.

The code doesn't seem to fit here, so i zipped it.
Can someone take a look at it? Thanks
http://www.mediafire.com/?zdcx5s93q9hxz4o

Comment: please try to reduce the code to a minimal example showing your problem (this might also help you find the problem yourself)

Comment: well, i can't reduce it because i don't know what's wrong, but i know the ' Snake.spawnPoint ' gets changed by ' Cam.move() ' , i forgot to mention this in the description

Comment: @andrew: You could just put two print statement around the place when integer changes into float to see if this is indeed happening. Do you do any division there?

Comment: Please read pep8 and use proper formatting and indenting, this code hurts my eyes.

Comment: well.. do I have to change the code to allow the camera to move smoothly? (i have velocity that changes by small amounts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers change to floats if you combine them in an expression, i.e. multiplication, addition, subtraction (not necessarily division). Most likely, some of your variables are floats, e.g. self.friction.

floats don't change back to integers by themselves, only through int(). If you observe anything else, you observe it wrong.

It appears your Move method modifies "spanwPoint" indirectly. I don't know if this is expected behavhiour, but it probably means you have two references pointing to the same list. E.g.

```
self.spawnPoint = [1, 0]
self.vel = self.spawnPoint # Does not make a copy!
self.vel[0] += 0.1
self.vel[1] += 0.2
```

will result in self.spawnPoint (also) being [1.1, 0.2]

Comment: uhmmm.. i have quite a  lot of move methods :D, which one are you referring to?

Comment: Looks like `Camera.SnapTo()` would be a culprit.

Comment: Thank you! i've been stuck on it for days, now i can go back to fun :), / so is it ok to use spawnPoint[:] to make a copy if it?

Answer (score 1):

In Python (as in many other languages) any simple arithmetic operation (e.g. +,-,/,*) involving an integer and a float evaluates to an answer that is a float. Integers never change into floats, it is the result of the operation that is returned as a float.

Note that the result of operations involving only integers is returned as an integer (I'm using the word integer to refer to both `int` and `long` in Python).